# How to generate or extract available date-time formats from locale settings like WordPad.exe shows?

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, wordpad

WordPad.exe shows several available Date/Time formats. Their number is different depending on default locale. I need enumerating all these formats in a unified way (in Python). It would be good to determine the number of formats at least. I could not find appropriate functions in standard `locale` and `datetime` packages.

The number of formats is 8 for `'ru_RU'`, it's 10 for `'en_GB'` and it's 13 or other number for some other locales.

Of course, I can automate WordPad.exe (by pywinauto or other framework) and get these formats from the app immediately, but I need another source of this info. Standard Python (2 & 3) modules usage is much preferable. If it's not possible, WinAPI functions are also OK.

[image: WordPad.exe formats for ('ru_RU', 'cp1251') on Windows 7 x64]

Comment: "Enumerating"? Or extracting? Or generating them given a locale? Please describe in more detail what is it that you're trying to do.

Comment: I need extracting or generating this info from locale settings not using WordPad.exe. If it's not possible using standard Python modules, WinAPI functions are also OK.

Comment: Frankly, this list of dates and times seems to me like WordPad's private thing. AFAIK Windows only has long and short format for date and time (dependent on locale).